# Email notifications on every commit to every branch on BitBucket server

Tags: commit, git-commit, bitbucket-server, email-notifications

How can we send email notifications to everyone whenever anyone pushes any code to any of the branches on Bitbucket server?

Every associated person who has access to the branch should get an email notification whenever any commit happens from anyone to that branch.

Can we do this in Bitbucket Server? Where can I find the settings for this?

We are using Bitbucket Server and not Bitbucket Cloud.

Thanks,
Yogini

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of Bitbucket you are using, instructions below are for 5.14.0 (latest version)

First you need to get each person to watch the repositories you are interested in, select a repository in the browser and then select 'Watch' on the right hand side of the screen:

[image: Watch repositories]

Then each person can configure what notifications they receive for repositories they are watching:

Select your profile icon on the right hand side, then select 'Manage Account', then select 'Watched Repositories'. In here you can customise the type of notifications you would like to get for each repository you are watching.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eeijlar . We are using Atlassian Bitbucket v5.7.0. Is there any way to get the same functionality in this version?

Comment: I will note that the "Watched Repositories" area of your profile *may not actually list* repositories that you are, in fact, watching. I just tried the watch button marked in this answer and found that it was generating emails (but had just prior looked at my account's watched repositories list, where it said I wasn't watching any) and was able to turn off the notifications.